# finding unique combination of vars and create a new var if found a unique combination

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe as toy example

```
aski = data.frame(A = c("x","y","z","x","z","z"),
                  B = c("a","b","c","a","b","c"))
```

Now i want to check for each unique combination of A and B and if its a unique combo i want to create a new variable in dataframe and increment each time(e.g r1,r2,....) a unique combintaion found.

Output dataframe something like this

```
aski2 = data.frame(A = c("x","y","z","x","z","z"),
                   B = c("a","b","c","a","b","c"),
                   output = c("r1","r2","r3","r1","r4","r3"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
aski2 <- data.frame(A = c("x","y","z","x","z","z"),
                    B = c("a","b","c","a","b","c"))
ref <- do.call(paste, aski2)
aski2$output <- paste("r", as.numeric(factor(ref, levels = unique(ref))),
                      sep = "")
aski2
```

Comment: but if have other variables in dataframe "aski2" other than "A" and "B".Suppose if dataframe is this `> aski2 <- data.frame(A = c("x","y","z","x","z","z"),
+                     B = c("a","b","c","a","b","c"), C = c("s","v","g","v","g","d"))`.How to proceed then?

Comment: i want to look for unique combo only A and B .Please answer this .I'll mark ur comment as answer then

Comment: In this case, you just need to compute the `ref` object using only columns `A`and `B`. This should work `ref <- do.call(paste, aski2[, c("A", "B")])`

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is use `group_indices`; Group by column *A* and *B*, and it *generates a unique id for each group* (see ?*group_indices*):

```
aski2 <- data.frame(A = c("x","y","z","x","z","z"), 
                    B = c("a","b","c","a","b","c"), 
                    C = c("s","v","g","v","g","d"))

aski2 %>% mutate(output = sprintf("r%s", group_indices(., A, B)))

#  A B C output
#1 x a s     r1
#2 y b v     r2
#3 z c g     r4
#4 x a v     r1
#5 z b g     r3
#6 z c d     r4
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is `.GRP`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(aski2)[, output := paste0("r", .GRP), .(A, B)]
```